# Apache Camel : CXFRS Server : Need advice for Routing

Tags: java, rest, apache-camel, cxfrs

i am making restful webservices using apache cxf and camel. my configuration is something like this :

```
<camelcxf:rsServer id="applicationserver" address="/" staticSubresourceResolution="true">
<camelcxf:serviceBeans>
<ref bean="Demo" />
<ref bean="Foo" />
<ref bean="Bar" />
</camelcxf:serviceBeans>
</camelcxf:rsServer>
```

I have three service beans exposed as services and are mapped to different urls and the route is something like this :

```
<camel:route id="ServerRoute">
<camel:from uri="cxfrs://bean://applicationserver" />           
<camel:process ref="camelCxfInProcessor" />
<camel:to uri="http://google" />
<camel:to uri="bean:googlereqreshandler" />
```

Now for each service bean i want to have different route as all three have different functionality, but i am unable to determine what should i write in my

```
<from: uri="cxfrs://bean://aplicationserver..."/>
```

tag to distinguish routes according to service beans. Or is there any other way of doing this?  please suggest something.

Comment: Posted the same question at : http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Apache-Camel-CXFRS-Server-Need-advice-for-Routing-td5699287.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Camel CXFRS documentation](http://camel.apache.org/cxfrs.html)? The approach they're taking in the example is to have one route that acts as a "catch all" and then takes different actions based on the value of:

```
String operationName = exchange.getIn()
                       .getHeader(CxfConstants.OPERATION_NAME, String.class);
```